# rewriting www to non-www and index.php CI

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgnter, as for a result all my links are like `base.com/index.php/home/index` or `www.base.com/index.php/home/index`.
I would like to display them only as `base.com/home/index` if possible.I have tried looking over the internet,got the rewrite in htacces from both of them as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [PT,L]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com\$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

put them separately,they work.But toghether they don't do what i need them to do.
Anyone knowing the solution?Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For CI, you want something like your first set of rules, but without the redirect. But the redirect needs to happen before the routing happes, so try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.base\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://base.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect direct requests to /index.php to remove it
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php/?([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://base.com/%1 [L,R=301]

# internally route to /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```